# how to make UnScrollable list with button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

can some one tell me how to make a long list with multiple widgets , but not scrollable , instead , there will be a **button** (like the arrow on the right in the picture) when you click it, it will slide to the next widgets available with the simple animation (not poping the current widgets sliding it instead), do we have a widget specified for that ? here is example of what i want :

[image]

Comment: Add `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Scrollable widget, set `physics` to the [`NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html) calss. For example:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
...
)
```